# Declaring specific user principal for environment in service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

Is it possible to define a principal user in certain environments?

If we look at the example `ApplicationManifest.xml` extract:

```
<Principals>
    <Users>
        <User Name="MyProductionUser" AccountType="DomainUser" AccountName="mydomain\prodUser" Password="abc123"/>
    </Users>
</Principals>
```

The `mydomain\prodUser` account only exists on the production environment, but as this `ApplicationManifest.xml` is used for all environments, deployment errors occur to my local dev cluster because this user does not exist. On my local dev cluster I want to use the NetworkService user as is default.

I have tried using parameters to set the AccountName etc, but this node does not allow parameters. I only want to declare this user when deploying to the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a release pipeline then you can tokenize your application manifest file when you build your artifact and replace the user principal at each environment.

We use VSTS and we use plugin to do this

- XDT transform to put token in the config for artifact.
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform
- Replace Token to change user principal per enviroment
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

If you dont have release pipeline and want to do it all on your machine then you can use slowcheetah

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms